# Title bar merging with menu - WINFORMS

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, winapi

I have a MDIContainer form. When the child form is maximized, its title bar is merged with menu.

**How can we avoid this merging?** That means the child form has to display its title bar in maximized state also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. This is how the multiple-document interface (MDI) works.

If you don't want this, then you don't want MDI.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, every "real" control in Windows is actually its own window.  You can also look at it such that windows are just controls.  This means that, if you had the time and patience, you could make your own MDI container using the Windows API by setting the parent of each window to your container control.  But having done it, I can guarantee that it will be a real pain, and I make no promise that you will actually get the effect that you want--at least, not without the cost of other problems arising.

Comment: Largely ranting reply. There is nothing wrong with the MDI concept and you don't really attempt to answer the question.

Comment: How's that for a better answer?